# AWS ALB Target Group Health Checks Failing for EC2 Instances – HTTP2 vs HTTP1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

I don't understand why my health checks are failing ("Health checks failed"). I have a dead simple setup with an ALB and an ASG with EC2 instances that are running node endpoints.

1. I can verify my health check endpoint is listening on port 8080. I can reach it just fine in my browser when I whitelist my IP address via security groups.
2. I can verify the EC2s are not receiving calls to the health check from my target group. pm2 adds no logs except for when I manually trigger it.
3. The target group has the correct path and port and protocol in the health check settings
4. My network ACL allows all inbound and outbound traffic. Route table for my public subnets (where the EC2s live) look fine

I duplicated all my infrastructure in the same VPC, using the same launch template and security groups, and now all of a sudden health checks pass. The only difference, as far as I can tell, is the duplicated target group uses HTTP1 instead of HTTP2. This single difference can cause health checks to fail? Is this documented anywhere?

If this is the cause, why is this the cause? If not, what else could I look at to solve this mystery?

Comment: Related which didn't give me an answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/990314/troubleshooting-https-on-aws-alb-target-group-health-check-failing